# does enriching Poco or Inteface, force recompile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, interface

I'm writing some service.

I'm asking 2 questions regarding 2 situations:

**Situations**

1) i use it "in-house", meaning as a referenced dll

2) I use it over the net, as webService

**Questions**

A)

If it exposes an interface to some client-class.
and now I added some method to that interface.

Do I have to recompile all its clients to recognize

the new interface even if they don't use the new methods?

B)

If a method in my service's interface expect some PoCo with property a,b

and one of the client calls that method with the same Poco type, but this Poco is defiened in the client-code as one that has a,b as before and also c,d.

Do I have to recompile the service? Does the contract breaks?

Comment: Interfaces **should** be considered immutable without recompilation. That said, the current implementation of .Net and Mono allows backward-compatible changes without breakage more often than not. I strongly recommend against relying on that.

Answer (score 0):

For web services, if you are *certain* that changes will happen, you may want to design a 'versioned' interface that takes generic arguments and a version number.  I have done this using an XML string that holds the contents of the parameters passed (XML string passed to web service a HTML encoded to avoid breaking SOAP envelope).
In the web service methods, checking the version number than proceeds to parse the XML into the expected type(s) for that method:

```
public void GenericWebServeceMethod(int version, string encodedXMLParameters)
{
    string xmlParameters = HTMLDecode(encodedParameters);

    switch(version)
    {
        case 1:
            ParameterType1 p1 = DecodeVersion1XML(xmlParameters);
            MethodVersion1(p1);
            break;
        case 2:
            ParameterType2 p2 = DecodeVersion2XML(xmlParameters);
            MethodVersion2(p2);
            break;
    }
}
```

When new versions are added, you extend the switch statement with new versions which still allows clients using older versions of the parameter types to continue working.

For a referenced DLL used 'in-house' you can force the reference to be version independent by adding the reference using the 'Browse' option in Visual Studio, and then selecting the reference's properties and ensuring that the 'Specific Version' property is set to `False`. Then you can still use a system similar to above to change the way than XML-encoded parameters are handled based on a passed version number.  Adding new methods is allowed but the calling client will not 'see' them until it it recompiled.